# how to make a Controls Item transparent

Tags: c#

As you know if you want to make your entire window transparent you probably use this code:

```
this.Opacity = 0.3;//or what ever you want...
```

And if you want to make your entire window do the same without its frame you use this code:

```
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
```

But what if I want to only make one item (for example my button) do this, but make all the other items (including the form frame and background) stay the same? What code would I use in this case?

tnx....

Comment: Replace `this` with control's name.

Comment: but button does not have TransparencyKey included

Comment: @Xaqron , you can't do that by replacing `this` with control's name

Comment: I would look into some Retro style tutorials, this sounds like you are after the windows 8 look and feel!

Comment: did you get any result ?